# Drupal build custom query between taxonomy and content

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7

I received a project that was coded by someone else on Drupal 7 but apparently does not follow any of Drupal's standards and was coded like a website with overwriting the template system (and it is too late to modify or edit any of the current structure).

I have the following issue to which I need to build a custom query:

The data in the CMS is created as such:

category (created in taxonomy) -> subcategory (created as a content type) -> item (created as a content type)

When adding the entries in the CMS, the workflow is as such:

1. first you create the main category from taxonomy (named Category)
2. the you create the subcategory from the contents
3. when adding/editing the subcategory, you select the parent Category from a radio list
4. and the items are selected from a checkbox list

I have taken screenshots from the CMS so help make things clearer regarding the structure, they can be found here:

> http://dropcanvas.com/qdokx/

The problem is that I am not being able to build the view for this at all,
I would need to create a custom query that can do the following:

1. read the Categories
2. Read the Subcategories belonging to each category
3. read the items under each category
4. with PHP, generate a custom HTML using loops on the above data

The purpose of this is so that on the website, user to be able to click a category, and to get a list of subcategories. When the subcategory is clicked, the items in it can be seen.

In typical PHP/MySQL, the query process would look like this (assuming no joins):

```
<?php
$categories = query('SELECT * FROM categories');
      while ($category = fetcharray($catetgories)) {
          $subcategories = query('SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE category = $category['id']);
          while ($subcategory = fetcharray($subcategories)) {
               $items = query('SELECT * FROM items WHERE subcategory = $subcategory['id']);
          }
       }
?>
```

I need to be able to replicate the above by doing a query to get items of taxonomy "Category",  find subcategories (content type) that belong to it, and then find items that belong to the subcategory

Comment: I have regretfully downvoted partly for the request for urgency, and partly because an answer came in and you did not accept, vote or reply to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Drupal API function [taxonomy_get_tree](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7) to get taxonomy tree and under each subcategory iteration use [EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.org/node/1517744) to load item (node) list.

But I recommend you to create custom AJAX field with three select form elements and load values dependently.